# How can I show my upper menu, above any icons and text?

Tags: html, css

I have an upper menu with the following CSS:-

```
nav {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#fff), to(#ccc));
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
     /*background: url('img/denim.png');
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;*/
}

.menu li a {
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 5px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin: 8px 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ededed), to(#fff));
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #fff);
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color: #222;
}

/* Dropdown styles */

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.menu ul li {
    float: none;
}

.menu ul a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Displays the dropdown on hover and moves back into position */
.menu li:hover ul {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Persistant Hover State */
.menu li:hover a {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ccc), to(#ededed));
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc, #ededed);
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color: #222;
}

.menu li:hover ul a {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#eee), to(#fff));
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #fff);
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Currently when the menu is displayed above an icon , the icon will occur above the menu text as follow:-
[image]

So is there a way to force the menu to be displayed above any text and icons ?
Thanks

Comment: John G, with that amount of reputation, is html code or a jsiffdle not to much asked.. is it?

Comment: @OP was the answer below helpful or do you still have the problem?

Comment: no still facing the same issue.. the below answer did not change the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Z-index to a high level on the menu and set the background color to solid white on the `.menu li` class as shown below:

```
nav {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#fff), to(#ccc));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  /*background: url('img/denim.png');
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;*/
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  /*background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);*/
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1); /* use this to make the background solid white */
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: i have noted that the Icon which is causing the issue have the following class :- .icon-comment {
  background-position: -240px -120px;
}

Comment: See my answer, the z-index: 1000 should be added to the `.menu li:hover ul` class

Comment: @johnG I have updated my answer with the correct CSS

Comment: yes this work , but still the menu is transparent , i mean the text and icon behind the menu can still be seen, which makes the menu label unclear. although the opacity is set to 1...

Comment: I have updated the `.menu li:hover ul` class in my answer. RGBA is Red, Green, Blue, Alpha (transparency). Please mark it if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the background-color opacity to 1 block out the rear elements.

```
.menu li:hover ul {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    ...
```